# Is this sentence correct? Where has all my energies gone by?

Tags: grammar

I've tried using this sentence

> Where has all my energies gone by?

but somehow I guess it's wrong. Could you please explain why this sentence seems to be incorrect English?

Comment: Please look up *energy* in a dictionary, and then tell us what you notice and if you still have this same question.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say, but this sentence is not idiomatic English.  Please add more detail to explain why you think it's correct, and perhaps we can write a good answer to explain why it's not correct.

Comment: No. It should be *where **has** all my **energy** gone* or *where **have** all my **energies** gone*. Neither sentence should have *by* at the end.